# CSS Styling Is Having Undesired Results In HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm having some formatting issues with my html page. The titles appear in two columns like they are supposed to, but they aren't showing the adequate spacing. Also, the submit button isn't the correct amount of space "down" from the end of the form.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Subscription Management System</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style1.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo">

    <div class="left_part">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/demo.gif"></a>
    </div>

   <div class="right_part"> 
        <div class="bigHead">Comic Subscription Management</div>
        <div class="littleNavi">
            <a href="../index.php?logout=1">LOG-OUT</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ADD</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="addstore.php">STORE</a></li>
                <li><a href="addpublisher.php">PUBLISHER</a></li>
                <li><a href="addtitle.php">TITLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="addsub.php">SUBSCRIBER</a></li>
                <li><a href="updatesubmaster.php">SUB DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a href="addfaq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="addemail.php">E-MAIL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="updatestore.php">STORE</a></li>
                <li><a href="updatetitle.php">TITLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="updatesub.php">SUBSCRIBER</a></li>
                <li><a href="addshortages.php">SHORTAGES</a></li>
                <li><a href="updatefaq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="updateemail.php">E-MAIL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">DELETE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="deletesub.php">SUBSCRIBER</a></li>
                <li><a href="deletefaq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="deleteemail.php">E-MAIL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PREPARE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="pulllist.php">PULL LIST</a></li>
                <li><a href="previews.php">DOWNLOAD PREVIEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="selectnew.php">NEW TITLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="editnew.php">NEW TITLE VARIATIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="editnewprice.php">NEW TITLE PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="editnewdetails.php">NEW TITLE DETAILS</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">E-MAIL</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="email.php">SUBSCRIBER</a></li>
                <li><a href="maillist.php">MAILING LIST</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>

<div id="contents">
    <h2>Add New Titles</h2>


                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Publisher Of Titles To Add:</b><br>
                            <select name="publishers">
                                <option value ="DC">DC</option>
                                <option value ="DC/Vertigo">DC/Vertigo</option>
                                <option value ="IDW">IDW</option>
                                <option value ="Image Comics">Image Comics</option>
                                <option value ="Linsner.com">Linsner.com</option>
                                <option value ="Marvel">Marvel</option>
                                <option value ="Zenescope">Zenescope</option>                           
                            </select><br>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Publication Status:</b><br>
                            <select name="status">
                                <option value ="active">active</option> 
                                <option value ="announced">announced</option> 
                            </select><br>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Discount Eligible:</b><br>
                            <select name="discount">
                                <option value ="1">yes</option> 
                                <option value ="0">no</option> 
                            </select><br>
                        </li>
                        <br><div class="col1">
                                <li>Title 1:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>    
                                <li>Title 2:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 3:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 4:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 5:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col2">
                                <li>Title 6:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 7:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 8:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 9:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>
                                <li>Title 10:<br><input type="text" name="titles[]"></li>                       
                            </div>
                        </ul>

                            <br><input type="submit" value="Add New Title(s)" name ="submit" id="submit">


                </form>


</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Administrator Control Panel </p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the css in question. Because the content is set to 900, there should be a buffer between col1 and col2:

```
/* Two Column Layout for Updates */
.col1    {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

.col2    {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
}

input[type="submit"]    {
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#contents {
    background:#fff;
    width:900px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

#contents {
    margin:46px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #888888;
    min-height: 550px;
    background-color:#F0F7FF;
    position:relative;
}
```

Here is an image of what the display is showing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move .col1 and .col2 outside of the last `</ul>`

That's invalid HTML and is probably causing the isuue